# Splitting a string in javascript and storing in multidimentional array

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
string s='2011/01/03 00:00:00,14.00|2011/01/03 00:00:00,14.50|2011/01/03 00:00:00",15.00|2011/01/02 00:00:00,12.00|';
```

I want to split the string first by '|' , which i can do by using

```
var ds=[];
 ds=s.split('|');
```

i further want to split them by ',' and store in an array

The question is how do i store in a multidimention array so the output looks similar to this

```
da[0]={'2011/01/03 00:00:00',14.00}
da[1]={'2011/01/03 00:00:00',14.50}
.
.
.
```

Thanks
Prady

Comment: If you really want a multi-dimensional array, see @patrickdw's answer for what the syntax looks like. Curly braces are for object literals (key/value pairs), not arrays (ordered values).

Comment: thanks Phrogz and patrick.. I was looking for an multidimentional array,, I had made a mistake by using the } instead of ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ds = s.split('|');

for( var i = 0, len = ds.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    if( ds[i] )
        ds[i] = ds[i].split(',');
}
```

Result looks like:

```
[
  ['2011/01/03 00:00:00','14.00'],
  ['2011/01/03 00:00:00','14.50'],
  ['2011/01/03 00:00:00','15.00'],
  ['2011/01/02 00:00:00','12.00'],
  ''
]
```

Comment: +1 for caching the length of the array, but -1 for multi-line statement without curly braces. :p

Answer (score 2):

```
var s='2011/01/03 00:00:00,14.00|2011/01/03 00:00:00,14.50|2011/01/03 00:00:00,15.00|2011/01/02 00:00:00,12.00';
var pieces = s.split('|');
for (var i=0,len=pieces.length;i<len;++i){
  var pair = pieces[i].split(',');
  pieces[i] = {};
  pieces[i][pair[0]] = pair[1]*1; //*1 to convert from string to number
}

console.log(pieces);
// [
//   {'2011/01/03 00:00:00':14.00},
//   {'2011/01/03 00:00:00':14.50},
//   {'2011/01/03 00:00:00':15.00},
//   {'2011/01/02 00:00:00':12.00},
// ]
```

This is assuming, based on your pseudo-JS syntax using curly braces, that you really meant an array of objects instead of a multi-dimensional array. If you want a single object hashing 'time-as-string' to values, you might do:

```
var pieces = s.split('|');
var values = {};
for (var i=0,len=pieces.length;i<len;++i){
  var pair = pieces[i].split(',');
  values[pair[0]] = pair[1]*1;
}
console.log(values);
// {
//   '2011/01/03 00:00:00': 14.00,
//   '2011/01/03 00:00:00': 14.50,
//   '2011/01/03 00:00:00': 15.00,
//   '2011/01/02 00:00:00': 12.00,
// }
```

This would allow you to find the value for any given day in constant time, without traversing the array of values.

Comment: I see you opted to interpret it as objects. You may be right. I'll give a +1 for that. :o) Oh, and for the number conversion as well. Good catch.

Comment: @patrickdw I suspect I'm not right; it makes little sense to have an array of objects with a single key each. I'll edit to add another possible guess, but I think you were right to go with the asked-for multidimensional array.